# YouTube Analytics API Core being deprecated

Tags: youtube-api

According to the documentation, all of the core metrics/dimensions are being deprecated.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/mets
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims#day

Why is that? Is there v2 being rolled out in future, or is YouTube just killing Analytics API? I can't seem to find any ETA till deprecation either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That actually doesn't say they are being deprecated; it just says that the core metrics/dimensions are subject to the deprecation policy.

In actuality, this is a good thing and a sign that the services are protected -- by being subject to the deprecation policy, YouTube has to give a certain amount of notice before deprecating them, and has to keep the services running for a period of time after deprecation. Anything not subject to the deprecation policy (such as the non-core metrics) could disappear at any time without notice.

In other words, the links you provide are just another way of saying that these are "production" services instead of "experimental" ones. See [this blog post](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2013/05/clarifying-deprecation-policy-for.html) for more details.

Comment: Well they could have cut the crap and explained what Deprecation policy means here https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube-api-list Thanks for explaining it to me.